# How to deal with troll user

Tags: discussion

This user (https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/13326/liu?tab=topactivity) submitted several answers in the last 9 hours, all of which seem to be nonconstructive comments. Is there anything we could do to prevent such activities other than flagging the answers individually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the community very widely, the tools are fairly limited: down-voting and flagging being the main options. Higher rep users have some more privileges (see here: https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). In particular, "trusted users" (4k+ rep) can vote to delete answers. Right now, there are only 7 users at that level, but the more people reach this reputation target the easier it will be for the community to self-police (another great reason to vote more, I guess!).

The mods have much wider powers, including deletion or destruction of the offending account. So our best response for the time being seems to be to try to be active in flagging bad behaviour for moderator attention. we'll try to respond as swiftly as we can. I have dealt with the specific case you mentioned. In the medium-long run, hopefully we can get a core of users with fairly wide policing privileges.